# What is the probability that smallest number is $6$ and largest is $15$?

Tags: probability, combinations

> Five numbers are drawn without replacement from the numbers $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$.  What is the probability that the smallest number is $6$ and the largest is $15$?

I am studying for a stats final and while working through this question I am a little confused, would someone be able to clarify this for me? Why is the numerator $\binom{8}{3}$?

[image: solution_to_probability_problem]

Answer (score 2):

The numerator is actually $\left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 2 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 8 \\ 3 \end{array}\right)$. You have to pick 6 and 15.

Also, you have pick 3 numbers out of the set $\left\{7, \ldots, 14 \right\}$, this set has 8 elements.